# lisp: consolidate a list-of-lists into a single list?

Tags: lisp, list

Still working on lisp recipes and idioms.

I have a list like this:

```
((a b c) (d e f) nil (g h))
```

I'd like to consolidate that to one list,

```
(a b c d e f g h)
```

Seems like there oughta be a one-liner for that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
(apply #'append '((a b c) (d e f) (g h i)))
```

or

```
(loop for outer in '((a b c) (d e f) (g h i))
      nconcing (loop for inner in outer collecting inner))
```

Comment: Perfect! - just what I needed.

Comment: `nconc` (and `mapcan`) can be bad for your health.

Comment: @eli: Certainly. But in the loop above it's fine, or is it? The inner loop returns fresh lists, so `nconc`ing is ok.

Comment: Dirk: Yes, I should have read this more carefully, and then put my comment next to Rainer's answer instead...

Comment: @Yongwei Xing: Because it destructively modifies its arguments. This is usually a bad idea, unless you know exactly that nobody else has access to the very same data structure. Here it should be fine, as the inner loop produces fresh lists, to which nobody but the outer loop can have reference to.

Answer (score 4):

That's a typical homework question. Generally this operation is called FLATTEN (which flattens lists on all levels).

```
(mapcan #'copy-list '((a b c) (d e f) nil (g h)))
```

The APPLY variant has the problem that it may run into the CALL-ARGUMENTS-LIMIT when there are more sublists than CALL-ARGUMENTS-LIMIT.

See for example also http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Flatten_a_list#Common_Lisp

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer.  It definitely was not homework for me.  Maybe 20 years ago, I might have had that as a homework question, but I can't remember that far back, now!

Answer (score 1):

In the vein of the answer involving `reduce` and `append`, you can also use the `:from-end` argument to `reduce`, which is much more efficient as it avoids the unnecessary copying of the result in progress because [`append` doesn't copy its second argument](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_append.htm#append):

```
(reduce #'append '((a b c) (d e f) nil (g h)) :from-end t)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `reduce` and `append`:

```
(reduce #'append '((a b c) (d e f) nil (g h)))
```

Unfortunately this is much less time and space efficient than the other solutions because it calls `append` a lot and copies the result-in-progress unnecessarily.